# Thmtools error: headformat not known

Tags: thmtools

I use the code given below to create a theorem box using thmtools, I get the error: `` Package thmtools Error: \declaretheorem key `headformat' not known ``.

According to the `thmtools` documentation, `headformat` is a valid argument to `declaretheoremstyle`. So I don't understand the error. Please help.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%% boxed theorems
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\declaretheoremstyle[numberwithin=chapter,
                    shaded={rulecolor=black!50, textwidth=0.95\linewidth, margin=0.8em, rulewidth=1pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}},
                    headformat={\NAME~\NUMBER\hfill\NOTE\smallskip\linebreak}
                    ]{sthm}

\declaretheorem[style=sthm]{hypothesis}


\begin{document}

\begin{hypothesis}[hypothesis name]
    Some hypothesis
\end{hypothesis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you Include `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\usepackage{amsthm}` then this seems to work.

Comment: the documentation is a bit unclear here, but these key definitions are only loaded if amsthm is detected.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to load `xcolor` and `amsthm`. I also added `headpunct={}` since presumably you don't want a stray period at the beginning of the line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%% boxed theorems
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\declaretheoremstyle[numberwithin=chapter,
                    shaded={rulecolor=black!50, textwidth=0.95\linewidth, margin=0.8em, rulewidth=1pt, bgcolor={rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}},
                    headformat={\NAME~\NUMBER\hfill\NOTE\smallskip\linebreak},
                    headpunct={}
                    ]{sthm}

\declaretheorem[style=sthm]{hypothesis}


\begin{document}

\begin{hypothesis}
    Some hypothesis
\end{hypothesis}

\begin{hypothesis}[hypothesis name]
    Some hypothesis
\end{hypothesis}

\end{document}
```

[image: hypotheses]